# Having trouble with figuring out how to loop and use isalpha() and isspace() together in a String Report

Tags: python

I am almost done with my code but I can't figure out two things.

First, I want to be able to say "You did not enter anything!" and end the program if a person enters zero characters in the string input at the beginning of the program.

Also, in the middle I have trouble figuring out how to use `isalpha()` and `isstring()` together. For example, if the string says, "dogs and cats" the program should output "Only alphabetic letters and spaces: yes."
However, if the string only has spaces or only has alphabetic letters then it should say, "Only alphabetic letters and spaces: no."

```
string = input('Enter a string: ')

length = len(string)
first_character = string[:1]
last_character = string[-1:]

print ('Length: ', length)
print ('First character: ', first_character)
print ('Last character: ', last_character)

if all(c.isalpha() or c.isspace() for c in string):
    print('Only alphabetic letters and spaces: yes')
else:
    print('Only alphabetic letters and spaces: no')

if string.isdigit():
    print('Only numeric digits: yes')
else:
    print('Only numeric digits: no')

if string.islower():
    print('All lower case: yes')
else:
    print('All lower case: no')

if string.isupper():
    print('All upper case: yes')
else:
    print('All upper case: no')
```

Comment: Just check `if not string` after getting input.

Comment: The fact that 75% of the answers given so far only address your first question and not your second one, is a good demonstration of why you should make separate posts for separate problems :-)

Comment: By the way, if you only want to refer to a single character in a string, you can just index it with `string[0]` or `string[-1]` rather than using slices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that empty strings evaluate to `False`:

```
string = input('Enter a string: ')
if not string:
    print("Nothing entered.")
    exit()
```

Use the built-in function `all` to help you with the next part:

```
if not string.isalpha() and not string.isspace() and all(i.isalpha() or i.isspace() for i in string):
    print("Passed!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, after you get the length of the entered string with `length = len(string)`, immediately perform your sanity check.

```
if length == 0:
    # do something
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped. I just did it and it worked.

However, I am a little confused for the second part of my question, it says that there are letters and spaces in a string that does not have them.

Comment: @Solenn check out TigerhawkT3's answer it contains an answer to your second question.

Comment: @JGreenwell oh I see thanks! I did not see it before.

Comment: If a string contains a whitespace then the length is not 0 anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if a string is empty by using:

```
if (word1 == ''):
    print('Empty')
```

Or if the string cointains whitespaces you could clear those out by using .strip()

```
word2 = ' '
word2a = word2.strip()
if (word2a == ''):
    print('Empty2')
```